# Is there a mythological creature that causes its viewer to commit suicide?

Tags: mythical-creatures

I've found a lot of creatures that kill, but not one that compels someone to commit suicide. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a known kind of creature native to Cambodia, they are known as Arakh. These spirits take possession of a victim and drives them to kill themselves. Only an exorcism can get rid of the creature and save the victim.

Hope this helps

https://occult-world.com/arakh/